# Does Windows phones have some kind of special sound processing?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an IR Transmitter (Deskpet http://www.mydeskpets.com/tankbot/) that sends IR signals via the headphone jack on the phone.
The software is availible on Iphone and Android (Source availible) so I decided to build a Windows phone version.
The app is really simple, just play a wav file and the device will send IR signals, but if I connect it directly to the phone it doesn't work however if I connect it to a BT-headset it works.
Does Windows phone have som kind of sound processing that is bypassed when using a BT headset or could it be a connector issue?
I have tested with HTC Titan and Nokia Lumia 800 same issues.

I have tested different volume settings and turned off the equlizer.

Answer (score 0):

I would record the output from the headset jack into something (line-in on a PC) and then compare the waveforms to see what is going on.

You should be able to see what the problem is then, and hopefully you can tweak the wav files you are playing so that you can get the proper output you need. As far as I know you can't detect when a bluetooth headset is hooked up, so if your tweaked wav files don't work over bluetooth you may need an in-app setting to determine which set of wav files to play.